# download files from text file that contain files list under linux

Tags: linux, centos, wget

i have a text file that contains a list of urls for files of my word

for example :

```
http://domain.com/file1.zip
http://domain.com/file2.zip
http://domain.com/file3.zip
http://domain.com/file4.zip
```

...etc

how can i batch download all files to a folder automatically from linux shell command

thanks for help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `man wget`:

> You have a file that contains the URLs you want to download?  Use 
>   the -i switch:
>
> wget -i <file>

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `cat /file/list`

do

    wget $i

done
```

(those are back ticks in the "cat /file/list" (on the same key as the tilda)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use xargs:

```
$ cat /path/to/list | xargs -n1 wget
```

or, using seq to download file1.zip to file10.zip:

```
$ seq 1 10 | xargs -n1 -i wget http://domain.com/file{}.zip
```

*[edit] or, as another poster pointed out:
    $ wget domain.com/file{1..10}.zip*

*which is nicer than the seq method, given that certain OSes don't have seq by default (Mac OS X, Solaris)*

Answer (score 0):

This command downloads file1.zip to file10.zip:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10);  do wget -nv http://domain.com/file${i}.zip ; done
```

Comment: if they were sequential, you could just do wget http://domain.com/file{1..10}.zip curl also has good support for file ranged, but I always forget the syntax.